# api google maps geocoding and javascript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

good night, you want to consult the following:

Conversing with an engineer , he tells me to look for an address with Google standard API ( Free ) has an error , since the marker is run or moved about 250 meters or more, not being accurate. a difference that google maps api premium ( for work) is accurate when looking one direction and this comes in the official Google documentation .

Is this true?

I just read the documentation and mentioned only the difference in the amount of credits and Support.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in accuracy for Standard plan and for Premium plan. As you correctly mentioned, the Premium plan users have higher usage limits and are entitled to technical support and SLA. Otherwise, this is exactly the same service.